# Merge two queries of entries ordered by publication date

Tags: entries, merge, query

I got a section called `news` which contain 2 types of entries: 
`news` and `press`.

Those entries are linked with 2 different categories :
`news` entries have category `newsType`
and `press` entries have category `pressType`.

In twig template I want to make 2 entries listing:

1. one from `news` entries and category `newstype = A`
2. the other from `press` entries and category `presstype = X`

Then merge those 2 lists to display them ordered by `publication date`?

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) parameter with multiple relation criteria:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['news', 'press']).relatedTo('or',
    { targetElement: newsTypeCategory, field: 'newsTypeCategoryField' },
    { targetElement: pressTypeCategory, field: 'pressTypeCategoryField' }).order('postDate desc') %}
```

Note that `newsTypeCategory` and `pressTypeCategory` should be category IDs (or CategoryModels) so you might need to pull the relevant categories as well:

```
{% set newsTypeCategory = craft.categories.group('newstype').slug('someslug') %}
...
```

Also note that you'll obviously need to change the `field` values to the real handles for your Categories fields, in the example criteria above.

*An alternative approach* is to use the [SuperSort plugin](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort) to sort two arrays of entries on the `postDate` attribute:

```
{% set newsEntries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(newsTypeCategory) %}
{% set pressEntries = craft.entries.section('press').relatedTo(pressTypeCategory) %}
{% set allEntries = newsEntries|merge(pressEntries)|supersort('sortAs', '{ postDate }') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old, but I was looking for a similar solution.

The other solution mentioned helped me get close, but ultimately, I wanted to use a native Twig [sort](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/sort.html) function, and I came up with this:

```
{% set one = craft.entries.section('firstSection').limit(10).all() %}
{% set two = craft.entries.section('secondSection').limit(10).all() %}
{% set entries = one|merge(two) %}

{% for entry in entries|sort((a, b) => a.postDate <=> b.postDate) %}
    {# do stuff here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: yes that just helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped! You can also switch to `b.postDate <=> a.postDate` for DESC order.